# Javascript if statement needs refactoring due to bad data

Tags: javascript

Javascript if statement needs refactoring due to bad data from my database.

I want a nicer way of doing this if statement:

```
if (typeof value === undefined || value === null || value === "" || value === 0) {
   return false;
}
```

Is there a shorter way?

I look forward to your suggestions.

Comment: `if (!value) {...}`, includes also `false`, though.

Comment: `typeof value === undefined` will never be true. The `typeof` operator always returns a string, it will never be undefined.

Comment: Or even `return (value)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could even do something like this:

```
return Boolean(value);
```

Comment: That will return `false` for values the OP hasn't said they want (`NaN`, `false`).

Comment: For Boolean(value) if value is null will it return false and if a string true?

Comment: @AngularM: `Boolean(value)` will return `false` for `false`, `null`, `undefined`, `""`, `NaN`, and `0` (the "falsy" values) and `true` for everything else.

Comment: yup, you can easily test in developer tools – but be aware of T.J. Crowder’s comment – if you don’t want to filter out `false`s and `NaN` then better use their suggestion

Comment: @AngularM: Yes. But there's exactly zero reason for the function call. `if (!value)` will filter out the falsy values.

Comment: @AngularM you should have really accepted T.J. Crowder answer :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I think it’s good to highlight the intention with `Boolean` and do coercion explicitly and I doubt it makes things significantly worse in terms of performance

Comment: @gryzzly: `!value` is 100% idiomatic. `Boolean(value)` is much, much less common and definitely not clearer. But it's a style thing, people can disagree.

Answer (score 7):

> Is there a shorter way?

Only slightly:

```
if (value == null || value === "" || value === 0) {
```

...because both `undefined` and `null` are `== null` (and nothing else is).

Alternately, in ES2015 you could use a `Set` of values you want to filter:

```
let badValues = new Set([undefined, null, "", 0]);
```

then

```
if (badValues.has(value)) {
```

If you also are happy filtering out `false` and `NaN`, then you can just use

```
if (!value) { // Does more values than your question asks for, see note above
```

---

Note that your first condition is wrong: If you use `typeof value` then `undefined` must be in quotes, because `typeof` always returns a string.

Comment: Type script doesn't like set

Comment: So I've had to use Boolean approach

Comment: @AngularM: TypeScript is perfectly happy with `Set` if you use the ES2015 interface definitions. You don't *have* to use the `Boolean` approach, see both the first and last of the three options above. The `Boolean` approach works (provided you do want to filter out `NaN` and `false`, which you didn't say in your question you wanted to do).

Comment: Will !value cater for undefined null 0 and empty string ?

Comment: @AngularM: Yes, that's why I said "also" above. When you use a value as a boolean, it's coerced to boolean exactly the way `Boolean` does the coercion. So `undefined`, `null`, `0`, `NaN`, `""`, and `false` (the "falsy" values) all end up being `false`, and everything else ends up being `true`. So `if (value)` will go into the `if` block if the value *isn't* one of those falsy values, and `if (!value)` will go into the `if` block if it *is* one of those falsy values. `if (value)` is exactly the same as `if (Boolean(value))` but without the function call. It's also (subjectively) more idiomatic.

Comment: !value vs boolean(value) are the same?

Comment: @AngularM: No, they're opposites. As I said in my comment, when you use a value as a boolean (e.g., in an `if` condition), it's coerced exactly like `Boolean` does. So `if (value)` is exactly the same as `if (Boolean(value))` and `if (!value)` is exactly the same as `if (!Boolean(value))`.

Answer (score 1):

Note that:

```
!!null === false
!!"" === false
!!0 === false
!!undefined === false
```

You can just write:

```
if (!value || !value.length) {return false}
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript automatically transform into boolean other variables types in if statement, you can do something like this:

```
if (!value || !value.length) {
   return false;
}
```

undefined, null and 0 are transformed into "false", meanwhile with .length, if it is 0 you will still have false, otherwise another number will be true.

Cheers

**EDIT**

for avoiding the object {length:0} to be parsed as empty, you can add:

```
if (!value || ((value instanceof Array || typeof value === 'string') && !value.length)) {
   return false;
}
```

Comment: Of course, that would also filter out `{length: 0}` (an object with a `length` property with the value `0` [or indeed, any other falsy value).

Comment: I edited the answer, but the data are so dirty and unpredictable maybe his solution is the best, apart from the `typeof value === "undefined"`, in which undefined should be a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (!value) return false;
```

proof - >

```
    console.log(!undefined, !null, !"", !0);
    returns -> true true true true

    console.log(!100, !"hello", !"0", !"false", !"true");
    returns -> false false false false false
```